# Setting calculated value for column for each group in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe where I need to group by column x and change all the values of column a in every group to a calculated, but constant value for each group.

I start with a dataframe like this:

```
x     |   a  |   b 
------+------+-----   
a     |  -1  |  ...
b     |  -1  |  ...
c     |  -1  |  ...
a     |  -1  |  ...
b     |  -1  |  ...
c     |  -1  |  ...
```

and want to transform it to the dataframe below by grouping by column **x** and changing column **a** to the return of function **f**

```py
p = ["k", "l"]

def f(group_number, list):    
    return list[group_number % len(list)]

x     |   a               |   b 
------+-------------------+-----   
a     |  f(ngroup(a), p)  |  ...
b     |  f(ngroup(b), p)  |  ...
c     |  f(ngroup(c), p)  |  ...
a     |  f(ngroup(a), p)  |  ...
b     |  f(ngroup(b), p)  |  ...
c     |  f(ngroup(c), p)  |  ...
```

*ngroup* is some function that does exactly what *pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup()* does- it returns a number for every group.

The overall result should be

```py
x     |  a  |   b 
------+-----+-----   
a     |  k  |  ...
b     |  l  |  ...
c     |  k  |  ...
a     |  k  |  ...
b     |  l  |  ...
c     |  k  |  ...
```

where all entries with **a** have the same value (**k**), all with **b** have value **l** and all with **c** have value **k**, too.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you add what your expected output for `a` looks like, instead of the function string we see now

Comment: Is your logic simply: when `x is a or c then k else l`?

Comment: the logic is: if I supply n values in the list `p`, I want to have 1/n of all groups to have the first, second, third, ... n-th value of p in column `a`. So In the case where `p` hast two values (`K` and `L`), I want to have half of the groups to have `K` and half to have `L` in column `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is

```
df['a'] = p[df.groupby('x').ngroup() % len(p)]  # TypeError here
```

Unfortunately, you cannot directly broadcast to a Python list so this will raise a

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series
```

But numpy ndarrays allow it, so you can just do:

```
df['a'] = np.array(p)[df.groupby('x').ngroup() % len(p)]
```

Comment: Perfect, this works, thank you!
Can you explain what you mean by "broadcasting to a Python list"?

Comment: @dfust Unsure whether it is the correct wording, because English is not my first language. *Broadcasting* is a numpy concept consisting in applying the same function to every member of an array in a vectorized way (meaning at C language level). What I meant is that you can only use integers or slices with a Python list, while you can use an array of indices for a numpy ndarray.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation helps me understand what happens and what the error in the first case is. Much appreciated!